# Remove border from matplotlib pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove the white border round the top and right of this plot?

this is the code I'm using to plot my pandas DataFrame:

```
plt.pcolor(diff,clip_on=False) # diff is a DataFrame
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(diff.index), 1), diff.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(diff.columns), 1), diff.columns, rotation=90)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: pcolor plot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the axis limits according to the data.  The quicker interface is through pyplot functions, - I think you want:

```
plt.ylim(0, len(diff.index))
plt.xlim(0, len(diff.columns))
```

but if you save the return value from `pcolor` then you can also set the limits.

```
h = plt.pcolor(diff,clip_on=False) # diff is a DataFrame
h.axes.set_ylim(0, len(diff.index))
```